# What is the proper modern spelling of the adjective endings -ыя, -ія?

Tags: правописание, дореформенная-орфография

These adjective endings are from a pre-revolutionary text: сознанія, хромыя, слѣпыя, безрукія. How would they be spelled today? (I know that ѣ is now е and і is now и.)

Answer (score 2):

I should have said "adjective endings." I found the answer at https://sites.google.com/site/seesscm/pre-reform-russian-orthography-cheat-sheet#h.mwz8ajkzeqru . The я becomes е.

Comment: _сознанiя_ is not an adjective, it's a noun and it's spelled _сознания_ nowadays. Otherwise, you're correct